# MariaDB 5.5-56 not reading the my.cnf file and taking default values

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

Permissions are correct. I actually went ahead and opened the file up to everyone (I know... big no-no but it's a closed off lab) any idea why MariaDB 5.5-56 wouldn't read the my.cnf file and just take default settings?

Comment: Can you provide any further information (error messages from the logs regarding reading the file)?

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux OS, make sure the file `/etc/my.cnf` is owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. It was already owned by root but the permissions were a little off. I started thinking that I copied the file from production over to the lab and apparently some permissions were not carried over. Once I mimicked the old file permissions, everything started working. Thanks!